# Disabling or configuring blinking (pinned?) tabs in Google Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, browser

I've noticed with the latest release of google chrome that any of my pinned tabs will start blinking if there is new (ajax) content available. It's mainly Gmail, Reader, Facebook, Twitter doing this at the moment.

I'm finding it extremely distracting. **Does anyone know how to disable the blinking tabs?**

Note, I do *not* want to close the tabs. I am thinking about moving my pinned tabs to a new window that's not always on screen, but I'd prefer not to do this.

Comment: For reference, the version of chrome in question is 15.0.874.106

Comment: related but not duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4825680/how-do-you-make-chrome-pinned-tabs-flash

Comment: See also [the Google Chrome support forum](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=1b2a3bd0f7990894).

Comment: Posted on [ticket](http://www.google.com/support/forum/p/Chrome/thread?tid=45f39699bf585e94&hl=en) on chrome support, thanks.

Comment: Given that the highlight of tabs has changed significantly in since you posted this question, does it still need to be open?

Comment: @OliverSalzburg This issue is still unresolved

Answer (score 5):

It seems that for both Chrome and Firefox, the only solution is to unpin the tabs. The tabs should not have this behavior unless they are pinned, and the flash is due to a change in the title of the page.

An alternative is to use an extension like [Stylish](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/stylish/fjnbnpbmkenffdnngjfgmeleoegfcffe?hl=en), which will allow you to modify the page template, potentially changing the title to a static value that does not change.

Answer (score 4):

You can try this on `Chrome`.

Create folder somewhere on your hard drive and create these two files in it:

#### manifest.json

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name"            : "Pinned Tab Flashing",
    "version"         : "1.0",
    "description"     : "Disable pinned tabs flashing",

    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["content.js"]
    }]
}
```

#### content.js

```
document.getElementsByTagName('title')[0].remove();
```

Navigate to `chrome://extensions/` and click on `Load unpacked extension` and choose the folder you created. Also you need to refresh your page.

Keep in mind that some pages like `soundcloud` for example are single page applications that load dynamically entire templates including their title tag, so this solution won't work there.

Comment: +1 for effort. I'll see if I can tweak this to only work on pinned tabs.

Comment: https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs#type-Tab says that the pinned state is just a property on the Tab object in chrome.tabs

Comment: @simo Does this still work in 2016? It doesn't seem to work for me